# Trocar variável tipo array entre 2 WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estou a fazer um website em ASP.NET onde tenho uma variável tipo array do tipo int num WebForm (chamaremos de `Default.aspx.cs`) e gostaria de passar essa variável para um outro WebForm (`Data.aspx.cs`).

Acho importante referir que a forma como estou a passar de uma página para a outra é usando o Server.Transfer.

Há alguma maneira de fazer um construtor que passe a variável para o Data.aspx.cs?

Gostaria também de adicionar que já usei o método seguinte mas não dava para especificar o index do array:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Page lastPage = (Page)Context.Handler;
                if (lastPage is WebForm2)
                {
                    Label1.Text = ((WebForm1)lastPage).dados.ToString();

                }
            }

        }
```

O `dados` é um método de encapsulamento com o array lá dentro.

Se notar aquilo que está errado e se me puder ajudar a usar este método que me é já um pouco familiar, faça favor de o fazer.

Comment: pode usar Session, já tentou?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Não conheço esse método. Poder-me-ia explicar como funciona ou direcionar-me para algum lado que me explique?

Comment: Session é um objeto no contexto do servidor que é um dicionário, ou seja, você pode armazenar um dado nesse objeto e fazer referência por uma chave,assim: `Session["Dados"] = dados`. Na outra página basta ler esse valor com a mesma chave "Dados": `var dados = Session["Dados"]`. Note que, na Session, tudo é `object`, ou seja, é preciso fazer um cast para poder reutilizar. Imagina que sua variável dados é um array de int: `int[] dados`, quando ler esse valor da Session, precisa converter: `var dados = (int[])Session["Dados"]`

Comment: @RicardoPontual é preciso fazer outro tipo de ligação entre os Forms?

Comment: @RicardoPontual no meu caso, iria declarar como Session["array"] = array; e no outro form declarar como ```int[]array = (int[])Session["array"];``` né?

Comment: sim, pode usar a chave "array", mas prefira algo mais explicativo se puder. Ah, como já vai fazer o cast para array, pode declarar assim na segunda pagina: `var array = (int[])Session["array"];`